In a sentence when two people are mentioned, would 'and' refer to the first person, or the second person?
In this sentence, would the 'and' be associated with Harry or Paul?

Harry hid in the trees until Paul arrived and picked the flower he had planted in the soil.

I feel like it's Paul (which is as intended), but if I placed a comma before the 'and' it would be Harry. I'm not at all sure though, and I've really struggled to find an answer to this question because I've not been sure how to ask it.
I can think of a few ways to rephrase the sentence to remove the ambiguity, but I'm really keen to understand how the it works (or doesn't) in its original form.
Edit: interestingly (or not) there was exactly this confusion on the BBC website this morning:

Gaza man says Hamas leader Yahya Sinwar was killed in his evacuated house

I thought that meant Sinwar had been killed in his own house, but the house actually belonged to the Gaza man. The headline is now:

Hamas leader Sinwar was killed in my ruined house, Gaza man tells BBC


I would say that it's definitely ambiguous without punctuation.

I don't see any real ambiguity. Either you do have a comma/pause before and (in which case Harry picked the flower), or you don't have a comma/pause there (in which case Paul picked the flower). Well, there is ambiguity - but only as regards whether it was Harry or Paul who originally planted the flower.

The sentence's meaning makes the association of punctive picking a well-identified flower with durative hid[ing] in the trees less felicitous. Perhaps 'Harry hid in the trees until Paul arrived and ate his customary bar of chocolate.' // There is certainly attachment ambiguity (which candidate is the compound predicate?) without a comma (though as said, Harry picking a flower while hiding seems unlikely). But a comma after arrived forces the association of picking with Harry (unlikely as the statement seems).

Logically it makes sense for one person to hide while the other picks, rather than for one person to hide and then come out and pick a flower after the other arrives. Grammatically there might be ambiguity but it's one of many cases where you need to engage your brain rather than try and solve it by mechanically applying syntactic rules.

Thanks everyone, that was very helpful. Another small worry put to bed. On the subject of engaging my brain, point taken (and I effectively revised the sentence out of existence in the end). But what was nagging at me was whether there actually was a syntactic rule, albeit 'technically correct' does not necessarily mean clear and unambiguous. 'Attachment ambiguity' is the phrase I was looking for—I've not come across it before, but it's certainly the question I was trying to ask.

@StuartF this is English, which is three-languages-in-a-trenchcoat.  Don't bring Logic into it !    Logic has no place here !

@tomjeatt welcome to the site - this is a good, well written question.  Keep it up !

@Criggie thank you!
